# Batman Arkham Origins closes immediately after splashscreen | Address = 0xc4a3e7 (filename not found)

Tags: steam, technical-issues, batman-arkham-origins

I've wasted the better part of my day trying to run Batman Arkham Origins single-player, but the game immediately closes as soon as I run it

[image]

There is no visible error message, but via a log file located in `steamapps\common\Batman Arkham Origins\SinglePlayer\BMGame\Logs` I got this:

> 2023.07.20-22.33.40 10506 364844 D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Batman Arkham
> Origins\SinglePlayer\Binaries\Win32\ Fatal error!
>
> Ozzy_[2014-03-07_09.25] 364844 2014-03-07_09.25.15 (Wwise: 2012.2.1
> #4427) Game
>
> Address = 0xc4a3e7   (filename not found) [in
> D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Batman Arkham
> Origins\SinglePlayer\Binaries\Win32\BatmanOrigins.exe]  Game

It would be very useful to know *which* goddamn filename was not found, but the log doesn't say.

I already did the following:

1. Update my GPU drivers (Radeon RX 6600)
2. Install all the updates to Windows 10 22H2 via Windows Update
3. Reinstall DirectX
4. Reinstall Visual C++ 2010 32 bit and 64 bit
5. Install NVIDIA Physx
6. Turn off antivirus
7. Run BatmanOrigins.exe as administrator
8. reinstall the game
9. verify the game files via Steam
10. add the parameters `-nostartupmovies` `-d3d9` and/or `-safe`
11. delete `SinglePlayer/BMGame/Config/BMEngine.ini`
12. reinstalled .NET framework 3.5

I'm fresh out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: This is a weird suggestion, but have you tried installing the game to a folder outside of the Steam\steamapps directory? IE try installing to C:\Games or something, if possible. Sometimes games get weird about the steam directory.